# Gradle annotation processing, SpringBoot 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, annotations

I'm trying to upgrade a project from SpringBoot 1.5.+ to 2.+, Its was not that hard and I only had to change a few lines of code. But I'm stuck on Gradle. I keep getting waring about annotation processes on class path and Ive tried to make changes that I found in another post of this site. But I still get the warning when following instructions I found here and on other sites.
As you will see I changed to using boot jar and you will see commented out code below my two annotation processes line. That was what I found I should change to but did not work.
Eg: replace `compileOnly` with two lines `annotationProcessor` & `implementation` which I tried for lombok and spring-boot-configuration-processor.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
//apply plugin: 'war'
//processResources {
//    expand(project.properties)
//}

version = '0.0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//war {
//    baseName = 'goolge-places'
//   // version =  '0.5.0'
//}
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
//springBoot {
//    executable = true
//}

repositories {

    jcenter()

    mavenCentral()

    /*
    // Private Oracle Maven repo
    maven {
        credentials {
            username '****'
            password '****'
        }
        name "maven.oracle.com"
        url('https://maven.oracle.com/')
    }
    */
}

configure(allprojects) {
    apply plugin: 'propdeps'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
}

// Change the output directory for the main source set back to the old path
// Gradle 4.0 change Deprecated. gone in version 5.0
//sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/main")

dependencies {

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
//    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    //compileOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-oracle:1.2.1.RELEASE'

//    compile 'org.springframework.metrics:spring-metrics:latest.release'
//    compile 'io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:latest.release'

    // Libs folder for oracle JBDC
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"
    //annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"
    //implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    //annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    //implementation('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"

    /*
    // Oracle DB Driver is in private Oracle Maven repo
    // I've created the maven settings.xml with hashed password
    // but it, "Gradle" dose not read settings.xml so I have set the
    //credentials above in the repositories section but now I get other errors
    // this fixed the auth errors but now I'm still getting a error
    // saying that the files do not exists
    compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
    */

//    compile('org.jooq:jool:0.9.12')

}


compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)


task removeOut(type: Delete) {
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    delete 'out'
}
```

Comment: when I create a brand new project in IntelliJ using SpringBoot 2 and LomBok my gradle file has `compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')` and that runs without any warnings.

Comment: please ignore that comment it is doing the same they had diff gradle versions

Comment: Are you using the gradle wrapper?
If yes, Did you upgrade it?
See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:upgrading_wrapper